# Php in Windows - exec output array character encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding, exec

I have a simple script that executes something like:

```
exec("x.bat", $array);
```

`x.bat` returns some special Latin characters, like áéí`'ñ, etc. They are completely garbled in the output array. I've tried setting both the page charset to Windows-1252 and sending "chcp 850" to the cmd before x.bat, but no matter, it always comes out garbled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this solved me the issue once also with special characters

```
exec("x.bat > result.txt 2>&1");
$data = file_get_contents("result.txt");
```

+make sure you are adding at the beginning of your php code, the header charset:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=Windows-1252');
```

Comment: Thanks! I got around to doing just that after a lot of fiddling; Shame there's  no easier way, but it worked fine.